# facing a SQL issue: near ".": syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have an error saying near ".": syntax error. I don't know how to fix it.

```
def createTable(table):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "{tablename}" (
        "id"    INTEGER,
        "snapshotTime"  TEXT NOT NULL,
        "open_ask"  REAL NOT NULL,
        "open_bid"  REAL NOT NULL,
        "close_ask" REAL NOT NULL,
        "close_bid" REAL NOT NULL,
        "high_ask"  REAL NOT NULL,
        "high_bid"  REAL NOT NULL,
        "low_ask"   REAL NOT NULL,
        "low_bid"   REAL NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
    );'''.format(tablename=table)
    )

    conn.commit()

def loadData(table, data):
    createTable(table)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.executemany('''
        INSERT INTO {tablename} 
        (snapshotTime, open_ask, open_bid, close_ask, close_bid, 
        high_ask, high_bid, low_ask, low_bid) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);'''.format(tablename=table), data)

    conn.commit()`your text`
```

I have an error saying near ".": syntax error. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: H, could you mention the line and character number? I would also like to see the error message from the console.

Answer (score 0):

For the table name replace double quotes with backticks or square brackets.

```
"{tableName}" should be `{tablename}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your create table scripts are wrong. If you are not passing in literals directly to SQL, you should not need quotations. Additionally, multi-line strings are usually made with double-quotes, rather than single quotes. I am not sure what version of SQL you are using, so I'm not sure about the specific syntax to use. However, here is the updated code:

```py
def createTable(table):
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tablename} (
        id            INTEGER  NOT NULL     AUTOINCREMENT,
        snapshotTime  TEXT     NOT NULL,
        open_ask      REAL     NOT NULL,
        open_bid      REAL     NOT NULL,
        close_ask     REAL     NOT NULL,
        close_bid.    REAL     NOT NULL,
        high_ask      REAL     NOT NULL,
        high_bid      REAL     NOT NULL,
        low_ask       REAL     NOT NULL,
        low_bid       REAL     NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );""".format(tablename=table)
    )

    conn.commit()

def loadData(table, data):
    createTable(table)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO {tablename} 
        (snapshotTime, open_ask, open_bid, close_ask, close_bid, 
        high_ask, high_bid, low_ask, low_bid) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);""".format(tablename=table), data)

    conn.commit()
```